# mPDF to output a local file + file inline to the browser

Tags: mpdf

I wanna know if i can output a pdf, using mPDF, to a destination as well as a preview in the browser at the same time. ie. I+F at the same time.

> I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if
>   available. The name given by filename is used when one selects the
>   "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
>
> F: save to a local
>   file with the name given by filename

My current code is like this:

```
$mpdf->Output($OutputLocation,F);
$mpdf->Output(); 
exit;
```

It can export the pdf file to $OutputLocation successfully, however, in the browser, it shows:

> mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send
>   PDF file

In the documents of mPDF, it has only show one option for one time, any methods to do both in the same output process?
http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is an issue on QNAP that their default php.ini is not allowing output buffering.

To solve this, I have edited the php.ini in the WebUI and change the output buffering to 4096. Then it works again.

```
output_buffering = 4096
```